# Помогите переписать AJAX запрос на чистый JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Я не силен в JS пока что, но нужно выполнить заказ и только из-за одного запроса не хочется подключать JQuery к сайту. Помогите переписать в JS пожалуйста

```js
  $('.ajax-post').click(function (e) {
  
    e.preventDefault()
    var post_id = $(this).attr('id')

    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      timeout: 8000,
      url: php_array.admin_ajax,
      type: 'POST',
      data: { action: 'theme_post_example', id: post_id },

      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var $ajax_response = $(data)
        $('#ajax-response').html($ajax_response)
      },

      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown)
      },

      complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {},
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const ajaxPost = document.querySelectorAll('.ajax-post')

ajaxPost.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()

    const url = php.admin_ajax
    const data = new FormData()

    let post_id = e.target.getAttribute('id')
    data.append('action', 'theme_post_modal')
    data.append('id', post_id)

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    })
      .then(
        (response) => response.text(), // Возвращаем текст из промиса
        (reject) => console.error('Fetch отклонён') // Обрабатываем ошибку
      )
      .catch() // перехватываем ошибку сервер
      .then(
        (text) => {
          document.querySelector('#ajax-response').innerHTML = text
        },
        (reject) => console.error('Ошибка на клиенте')
      )
      .catch() // перехватываем ошибку фронтенда
  })
})
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]